# 2005 Honda Pilot problems

Tags: engine, honda, head-gasket, temperature, emergency

Okay so my car is at 215380 miles. It was having radiator problems and Water pump problem. The water pump turning belt had disengrated from being in the car for a long time. The engine still wasn’t damage. I had the mechanic replace and fix all that. It was ready. I paid and left. When I left I noticed the check engine light was on. But I didn’t know what it meant. I am a new driver and new to cars. It didn’t say check engine it showed the engine and it was yellow that’s about it. It didn’t actually say check. I have never seen that before even driving the car with radiator and water pump broken as I brought it to mechanics. As I was driving after getting gas. The car made a weird sound. I didn’t know it was my car. Then I saw weird white smoke. Kind of thick. I kept driving and someone told me to pull over to check the problem. So they did and the holes to the radiator wasn’t connected. He barely put it on. Another person with pliers came and put it on. I went back to the mechanic and they said the head gasket may be broken.. which is weird because the car was fine. The temperature gauge wasn’t above the boat. It didn’t go to high at all. Until the hose popped off. On my way There the temperature gauge didn’t move to H for Hot. Because everything was good. My friend came to help. And We put coolant in it so we can make it back to the mechanic with no problem. Smoke was still coming from the vehicle. We got there and the temperature gauge didn’t move it was just little smoke here and there. White smoke the smoke wasn’t any color. But white smoke. So they fix the hose and refill the coolant. White smoke was still coming out of the car hood. But after a while it stopped. This is when he told me to bring the car back tomorrow. As I was driving home I was having problems with the car thermostat it will go to H. Even the car was fine. The car was running fine. Nothing would get stiff like if the engine heated up. But I stoped anyway to let the car cool down. And it went down allot sometimes. And it was tricky... when I was parked in my driveway I turned the car on and it didn’t go up at all. It was like 1/3rd about the C.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What exactly is your question?

Comment: If the vehicle is low on coolant, or has an air bubble in the cooling system, temperature gauges can not function normally, staying on Low even while the engine is overheating, occasionally bouncing to H. Since you lost a lot of coolant due to a disconnected hose, I think this explains your temp gauge.

However the Pilot requires a coolant fill procedure. You may still have a trapped air bubble, and your engine may overheat again until properly burped.

Was it steam or smoke coming out? What is the current vehicle condition? You may have blown a head gasket due to the engine overheat.